# Why does address of self change when execution is in method didMoveToView?

Tags: objective-c

I have a Mac OSX Objective C project that has me confused.  Xcode Version 7.3, Deployment Target 10.11.  The project, built using IB, does nothing more than display an animated sine wave, and does so as a sprite.  I'd like to control the speed of the wave, and for simplicity just slow, medium, and fast, as selected using a radio matrix.  There are four source code files:

```
//AppDelegate.h
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSMatrix *radioRef;
@end

//AppDelegate.m
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "SineWave.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) IBOutlet SKView *skView;
@end

@implementation AppDelegate
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    [self.radioRef selectCellWithTag:1];
    SKScene *scene;
    CGSize size     = CGSizeMake(360, 216);
    scene           = [SineWave sceneWithSize:size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeFill;
    [self.skView presentScene:scene];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}
@end

//SineWave.h
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
@interface SineWave : SKScene
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) IBOutlet SKView *skView;
@property NSArray *walkFrames;

- (IBAction)radioAction:(id)sender;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSMatrix *radioRef;
- (void)      didMoveToView : (SKView *) view;
- (NSArray *) animationFramesForImageNamePrefix: (NSString*) baseImageName frameCount: (NSInteger) count;
@end

//SineWave.m
#import "SineWave.h"
@implementation SineWave
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    CGFloat ThisSpeed = (CGFloat) self.radioRef.selectedCell.tag;
    if (ThisSpeed < 1.0)
        ThisSpeed = 1.0;

    self.walkFrames = [self animationFramesForImageNamePrefix:@"SinWave" frameCount:45];
    // Create the sprite with the initial frame.
    SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[self.walkFrames objectAtIndex:0]];
    sprite.position      = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    [self addChild:sprite];
    SKAction *animateFramesAction = [SKAction animateWithTextures:self.walkFrames timePerFrame:0.05];
    [sprite runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:animateFramesAction]];
    sprite.speed = ThisSpeed;
}

- (NSArray *)animationFramesForImageNamePrefix: (NSString*) baseImageName frameCount: (NSInteger) count {
    /* Loads a series of frames from files stored in the app bundle, returning them in an array. */
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];
    for (int i = 1; i<= count; i++) {
        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%03d.png",baseImageName, i];
        SKTexture *t = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:imageName];
        [array addObject:t];
    }
    return array;
}

- (IBAction)radioAction:(id)sender {
    CGSize size     = CGSizeMake(360, 216);
    SKScene *scene  = [SineWave sceneWithSize:size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeFill;
    [self.skView presentScene:scene];
}
@end
```

These are the connections:
    sKView 
    Accessibility:            link and title = none
    Referencing Outlets:      skView -> Sine Wave and Delegate
    Accessibility References: link and title = none

The radio matrix
    Outlets:                  delegate, formatter, menu, and nextKeyView = none
    Sent Actions:             action -> Sine Wave and radioAction
    Accessibility:            link and title = none
    Referencing Outlets:      radioRef -> Sine Wave and Delegate
    Received Actions:         all elements (performClick ... takeStringValueFrom) = none
    Accessibility References: link and title = none

The Object (of class SineWave)
    Outlets:                  Radio Ref
    skView:                   Sk View
    window:                   Window
    Referencing Outlets:      none
    Received Actions:         radioAction -> Radio Ref

The code to build and execute the sprite works and the display is a nice sine wave rolling across the view (skView in file SineWave.h, line 6), but only at one speed.

The radio matrix has tags Slow=1, Medium=3, and Fast=6, in the hope of producing ThisSpeed values of 1.0, 3.0, and 6.0.  What has me perplexd is radioRef has value nil while execution is in method didMoveToView.  How can/should I obtain the selected cell of the radio matrix in method didMoveToView?

Answer (score 0):

> Why does address of self change when execution is in method didMoveToView?

It doesn't, you have 2 or more distinct objects.

The method `sceneWithSize:` which you call in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` creates a *new* object. If you have connected the `IBOutlet`s in `SineWave.h` in IB then you also have a `SineWave` object in your xib - so you've got two objects.

HTH